# How to process multiple Spark SQL queries in parallel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I have something like

```
df1 = sqlContext.sql("select count(1) as ct1 from big_table_1")
df2 = sqlContext.sql("select count(1) as ct2 from big_table_2")
df1.show()
df2.show()
```

Within each table (either Hive or temporary), the rows will be counted in parallel across the worker nodes, assuming the underlying dataframe is partitioned.

Is there also a way I can get the two *tables* to count in parallel?
Is this even possible in PySpark?

Comment: Why don’t you do union all if it’s just a count.

Comment: It might not be. I'm just giving that as a minimal example